# Determining the method of calculating p-values for regression

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I would like to know any kind of method I can use to find out which distribution was used to calculate the p-values in this regression output table, thanks.
[image: Only information given]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems they´ve used the t-distribution. The t-distribution is symmetric and we are looking for the sum the yellow colored areas, denoted with $1$ and $4$. This is $2-2\cdot F_n(|t|)$, where $F_n(|t|)$ is the cdf of the t-distribution. The degrees of freedom are $df=48-2=46$. For instance, we take $|t|=1.072$. Then we use a [calculator](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/t-distribution.aspx) and see that $F_{46}(1.072)=0.8553$. Therefore the p-value is $2-2\cdot 0.8553= 0.2894$

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @user3486373 You´re welcome.